# Java recursion and retain information

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I have a method that needs to loop through nested elements and return a string which should be concatenated as a result of the lopping through the tree. from searching, i believe recursion will be a easier method but I am unable to get the results desired.

Structure of data:

```
root
  child 1
    child 1.1
    child 1.2
  child 2
    child 2.1
    child 2.2
      child 2.2.1
  child 3
```

Okay that is the idea. I need to loop though starting from a child to find the path to the root by list the element from the child starting point to the root.

Eg: I am looking for child 2.2.1. The return answer should be:

```
child 2.2.1,child 2.2, child 2, root

Private String loopthrough(String name, String needed LinkedList myList)

        List<String>Children = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String child : children)
        {

            if (child.isParentOf(needed ))
            { name+=child.getName
             }
            else{
                goneThrough.add(child);
            }
        }
        children = goneThrough;

        for (String child : children)
        {
            loopthrough(child);
        }
```

Comment: Please add what code you have so far, and what part of the problem you are having problems with.

Comment: @Keppil i included the code

Comment: Please explain why you vote down, or give an answer if you have it!

Comment: Down vote could be because you have posted code but not explained in what way(s) it does not address your problem.  For example, why your code as posted does not compile.

Comment: You wrote __starting from a child to find the path to the root__ so if the interface of the data structure is in your hand simply add a `getParent()` method to it and call `getParent()` until you reach the root node. If you just have the `isParentOf` method `getParent` can be implemented by iterating over all nodes one layer above your current node in the hyrarchie. (like said this applies only if you really start at the child node...)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid recursion by pushing the nodes you visit on the desired path as you descend the tree, so that they will get popped off in the order you wish to display them in.

Comment: this issue is that not every node i visit needs to be include, only the one to which trace the element back to the parent. Eg: In search for 2.2.1, I may visit 1, but 1, does not need to be included

Comment: So only push the ones that need to be included ("on the desired path").

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder (or PrintWriter, or StringWriter) as in-out parameter.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder():
tree.dumpTree(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
String s = sb.toString();
```

This has the additional advantage that not a on every call a concatenation of Strings to new Strings happens.

---

In this case you can build a result on coming back from the recursion. I still do not understand what your data structure is, and what would be the correct parameters. With String:

```
private String loopthrough(String name, String needed, List<?> myList)
{
    if (name.equals(needed)) {
        return name;
    }

    for (String child : children) {
        String partialResult = loopthrough(child, ...);
        if (partialResult != null) {
            return name + " " + partialResult;
        }
    }
    return null; // Not found in this subtree.
}
```

Of course we cannot know the datastructure you are using. I assume here, that `children` are the immediate child nodes. And in the recursion one would rather parse the node, that the name String.

Comment: The data is not necessarily a tree, it just has the structure. Also can you explain more?

Comment: We here need to know which data structure you are using, evidently not a list of indented strings. One could for instance maintain a list (stack) of immediate parents. On finding the `needed` one then can construe the result. I'll give a hint in the answer: